# Give height to the image object using javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, javascript-objects

I am trying to give height to an image object using javascript, But its not working.

**html code**

```
 <canvas id="canvas1" height="500px" width="500px">

 </canvas>
```

I want to create background image using javascript and this image must be set according to canvas size.

**Javascript code:**

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var bg = new Image();
bg.src = "images/bg.png";
bg.height = "100";
bg.width = "100";
c.drawImage(bg,0,0);
```

I can see the image but can not give the height and width of that image at run time.
How can i give the height and width of image object at runtime.?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in the code:

### Issue 1

The first one being the tag attributes. Doesn't really affect the result but the correct syntax is an integer value without `px` at the end as width and height for canvas can only use pixels:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
```

### Issue 2

The next issue is that you try to set **read-only** properties on the image element:

```
var bg = new Image();
bg.src = "images/bg.png";
//bg.height = "100";      invalid
//bg.width = "100";       invalid
```

You don't really need to set the image size; you *can* if you absolutely want by using this syntax (then get actual size using `naturalWidth` / `naturalHeight` if you should need them later - the full image will be loaded in any case):

```
var bg = new Image(width, height);
```

But you can simply use width and height with the `drawImage()` method (see below).

## Issue 3

The third issue is that you don't allow the image to load. Image loading is asynchronous so you need to add an `onload` handler:

```
var bg = new Image();
bg.onload = done;         /// wait for image to load, then call done()
bg.src = "images/bg.png";

function done() {
    c.drawImage(bg,0,0);
    /// continue here
}
```

Optionally define the destination size like this:

```
function done() {
    c.drawImage(bg,0,0, width, height);  /// the size you want
    /// continue here
}
```

If you want to fill the canvas use:

```
c.drawImage(bg,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's on a canvas you need to set them in the drawimage function

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var bg = new Image();
bg.src = "images/bg.png";
c.drawImage(bg,0,0, 100, 100);
```

Comment: c.drawImage(bg,0,0, 100, 100) is working.. But what to do if i want to apply this for more than one image.. Its must be dynamic.. Here are we are giving static height 100.

Comment: @RikinThakkar it's working on your local computer but won't on an external server as this code isn't handling image loading..

Comment: @Ken It means this code will not work dynamically..?

Comment: @RikinThakkar it will work dynamically, but as image loading is async. you need to wait for the image to load. This is why you need to add the onload handler and continue from there. If you try to draw the image before it has loaded it will turn up blank.